# Builder that calls a Python function that in turn goes into wait state

Tags: python, asynchronous, builder, scons

What's the most convenient way to define a `Action` in SCons that executes a Python function whose execution goes into wait state for *long* time?

If that Python function in turn calls `env.Execute()` and waits for it to complete will the SCons scheduler flush out the execution of that Python-based Builder until the call to `env.Execute()` has completed?

Comment: You are mixing two different concepts here. Execute is meant for commands that should get run while the SConscripts are read. An Action describes the exact build steps that are required for creating the target in question, once the TaskManager has found that it's not up-to-date and the scheduling has assigned this very task to a worker thread. It doesn't make sense to call Execute within an Action...please clarify your question accordingly.

Comment: As @dirkbaechle said. This is an odd question.  Can't think of any reason to do this. Please post source code so we can see what your doing to give you an appropriate answer.